# Read analog value with microcontroller without ADC

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, adc, microchip, digital-communications

I have an AT89S51 microchip from Atmel. I want to read a value from a node in a circuit that can be either ~0V or ~5V (it's the output of a comparator, so the comparator itself is my ADC).

Is it possible (and safe) to do this without having to implement an ADC, for example, connecting the node directly to the pin P1.1 of the AT89S51?

Comment: As in a 1 bit A/D convertor.  No problem as long as the pin +5V compliant.

Comment: if you replaced the output of the comparator with a mechanical switch that selects between two voltages, a +5 V and a 0 V, then would you still ask if it is safe?

Comment: Although from some people unfortunately try to include "synchronous" in part of their definition of "digital signal", that's not an essential part of being a digital (discrete amplitude) signal, and a comparator output is perfectly fine to connect to a digital input pin, possibly with a voltage divider to account for mismatched voltage.

Comment: If you are only interested in the signal being at 0V or 5V then it is the same as any digital signal.  If you are interested in a simple A/D channel for detecting the values between 0V and 5V (as per your question's title), then there are a few alternatives, namely feed a filtered PWM voltage to the opposite comparator input simulating a DC value, or you could charge then discharge a cap on that same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the signal is either 0 V or 5 V, and you don't care about any intermediate values, it is a digital signal.  It is perfectly normal to connect it to a digital input on your microcontroller, as long as the microcontroller's Vcc is 5 V.

Comment: Is it safe to do so? It's because I can't find any documentation of doing this (only through using ADC). Can it be done at any input port of the IC?

Comment: It's totally safe, as long as the microcontroller can tolerate 5V at that input.

Comment: @ludicrous why would it not be safe to connect a digital signal to a digital input

Comment: If the comparator has an open drain or open collector output, there will be no problem if you use a pull-up (internal or external) to the microcontroller power supply. Otherwise you may need to make sure the comparator output does nor exceed the microcontroller's DC supply, or use a series resistor to limit the maximum current through the protection diodes.